# If I'm using ls and grep, how do I specify the directory I want to search in?

Tags: regex, grep

I can do the question I need to do if I cd into the right directory, but our prof wants us to be able to do it from anywhere.

I can do `ls | grep *pattern*` and it works from the directory I'm in, but how do I do it anywhere by specifying the path?

Comment: Have you tried `man grep`? I recommend doing so...

Comment: Smells like homework.  Read up about how to use the `ls` command here. http://www.columbia.edu/acis/rad/unixcmds/ls.html  It will be more useful than us just telling you the answer.

Comment: What about `find /path -name pattern`?

Comment: My one final question is how I'd achieve "whose names do not start with either a lowercase or an uppercase English letter." I tried ls | grep '$[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*$' but it didn't work.

Comment: Almost everything that you may be tempted to write using `ls | grep` is much better written using `find` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls /path/to/directory | grep *pattern*` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching a directory for a specific files then I would recommend using `find` command. `grep` is generally used to search for content in a file and either list out the content of the filename.

To search for any type of file from anywhere you can do -

```
find /path/to/search -type f
```

This will list out all files recursively if that directory has subdirs. You can control that using `-depth` option. You can also use `-name` or `-regex` option to find specific files. Man page for `find` has all the info with example.

> My one final question is how I'd achieve "whose names do not start with either a lowercase or an uppercase English letter

```
ls -1 | grep "^[^a-zA-Z].*"
```

***^ and $:** These are anchors which points to (^)start and end($) of the string.*
***[^..]:*** When ^ is inside a character class it negates the content of character class.

Comment: I'd love to, really, but my prof unfortunately is requesting we start the command with ls, so I need to pipeline it. These worked beautifully, though.

My one final question is how I'd achieve "whose names do not start with either a lowercase or an uppercase English letter."

I tried `ls | grep '$[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*$'` but it didn't work.

Comment: @DougSmith Added that in the answer. Good luck!!

Comment: Why the ending character?  I thought he only cared about the starting character?  `"^[^a-zA-Z]"`

Comment: @JeffB Oh my bad! I thought I read names not starting **and** ending with english letter. Have fixed it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `find` also?

```
find | grep "pattern"
```

It should work! Or if you're looking to a pattern in the directory name, you should do

```
ls -R | grep "pattern"
```

This searches recursively into your directory tree.

That's it.